# Container stick or stack to header. position fixed

Tags: css

Hi guys, I use `position:fixed` for my header. After that, I tried to use a container, but I not sure why it is inside the header (Stacked). I tried use margin-top to separate container from the header, but its not working because the header also used the margin-top..

Here is my **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X6mTZ/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .header class you have to add top: 0px:

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 120px;
    background: #232323;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0px;
    }
```